# Get all products where average rating is equal to 5 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 Tables Products and Reviews

- Products hasMany reviews
- Reviews belongsTo Product

I want to get only those product which have avg('ratings') is equal to 5

from controller, I get `products = Product::with('category')->with('reviews')->get();`

now want show in blade in one part of Top Rated Products

`$product->reviews()->avg('ratings')`
I used this to get average ratings for a single Product.

Now I want to get a collection of products which has average rating = 5. I tried this line

```
$products->reviews()->avg('ratings')->where('ratings',5)->take(3)
```

but this not worked. Can anyone please help me with my problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try something like that:

```
$products = Product::with(['category', 'review'])
    ->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.product_id', '=', 'proucts.id')
    ->select(['products.*',
        DB::raw('AVG(reviews.rating) as ratings_average')
        ])
    ->where('ratings_average', 5)
    ->get();
```

You might want to experiment a bit with the syntax as I'm not quite sure that will work, but you should get the idea of what we're trying to do.

**EDIT**

In case you already have your collection as `$products = Product::with('category')->with('reviews')->get();`, then you can even simplier filter it using:

```
$productsFiltered = $products->filter(function($product){
    return $product->reviews->avg('rating') == 5;
});
```

Comment: I already have a collectios of products. I want to filter from this collection.

Comment: ```products = Product::with('category')->with('reviews')->get();``` from this

Comment: it says ratings_average not found

Comment: Is it possible to add paginate() with this? I tried, but it say paginate not exist

Comment: @tariqulanik It wouldn't be possible on a preloaded collection as `paginate()` is a method of the eloquent query builder class. You would need to call it respectively on your query. That's why I'd recommend using a query to filter your products.